# java regex for date format extracts wrong information

Tags: java, regex, date

I am using regex to figure out what format the input date is. This is one of the patterns i am using

```
    ^((18[5-9]|19[0-9]|20[0-9])\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

so the constraint is to have the year between 1850 and 2099. If I pass for instance this string as date 20011212 when I am extracting the year, month and day from it, this is what I get: year: 2001, month: 200, day :12. Any Idea why?

```
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(dateString);
    if (matcher.matches()){
       matcher.reset();
       if (matcher.find()){
          Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
          Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
          Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
       }
    }
```

The code is simplified, but even on this simplified version, it returns erroneous results. Thank you for any suggestions/solutions.

Comment: what results are you getting?

Comment: year: 2001, month: 200, day :12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a regex everything you put inside `(...)` is a capturing group. You have two groups in the year, those are both capturing groups:

```
group(1) = ((18[5-9]|19[0-9]|20[0-9])\\d)
group(2) = (18[5-9]|19[0-9]|20[0-9])
group(3) = (0?[1-9]|1[012])
group(4) = (0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

You can also use non capturing blocks like this: `(?:...)`

So your pattern should be:

```
^((?:18[5-9]|19[0-9]|20[0-9])\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

Comment: The parenthesis are good there, to allow another digit for the year, if not it considers the year on 3 digits.

Comment: Yes, but you need to specify that that is a non-capturing group.

Comment: +1 You are also right. Thank you for clarifying. I didn't knew the trick for non capturing

Answer (score 4):

The second group is the first three digits of the year, use a non capturing group for it:

```
^((?:18[5-9]|19[0-9]|20[0-9])\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to `^(18[5-9]\\d|19[0-9]\\d|20[0-9]\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$`. You had a pair of parentheses too much around the first 3 digits of the year that created the second matching group.

Comment: Yup, you were right. I thought I can put the \\d after all the constraints. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have a capturing group (a pair of parentheses) inside the year regex. You can either:

- count the left brackets and select the correct ones. Hard to maintain if you are ever going to change the regex in the future.
- use named groups. Not all regex flavors support this. I think Java is one of those who don't.
- use non-capturing groups.

A non-capturing group is denoted by `?:` at the start of the group:

```
^((?:18[5-9]|19[0-9]|20[0-9])\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
   ^^--- here
```

Note that look-arounds (`(?= ... )`, ...), are non-capturing as well.